# How To Reverse Engineer Forecast From Data Set

Tags: excel, reverse-engineering, forecasting

I have a list of foretasted data pasted as values, I would like to continue to produce forecasts in the same format but do not have the formula to how the originals was created.

I am trying to recreate the current forecasts as to prove the working formula, but cant seem to find the correct algorithm. I have tried multiple logical formats from using average, averageifs, forecast, trend and of all different relevant date ranges and cannot reproduce the original or anywhere near.

The data set it too large and sensitive to post here but please see example of data format below:

```
Date      Actual   Forecast       #Data goes back up to 3 years
19/06/19   121      138
18/06/19   110      116
17/06/19   129      124
```

I would like the calculation method used for example receiving 19/06/19 Forecast from the past data of Actual column.

I am unsure whether VBA could be used to cycle through possible options as I have never had to do anything like this before? Hopefully someone with more experience than me may have a more of an idea.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: Do you know the input data on which the forecasts were calculated? Did you ask around who created the excel in the first place, and the formulas for forecasts?

Comment: Yes, I have all the data. There is only 3 columns 3 years back, the person who created the formula is no longer available to contact. And I also have a feeling that it was a multi layered formula of averages and trends. I was wondering if there is such a thing as a vba machine learning loop that will try and get as close to the result as possible using available data?

Comment: Are the numbers in the present the same as the numbers in the past? If not, then it is more difficult.

Comment: Yes, the past data never changes. The future forecasts will change day by day as new date is input, but once the day has passed the data never changes.Please also note, data above is just filler date not actual values.

Comment: :) I meant, the current data for calculating the forecasts, is the same as the data in the past? If yes, you can just re-use the forecasted values from the past. If not, some "heavy" mathematics / statistics may be necessary.

Comment: Im not sure I understand, every day a new line of data is added (Date & Actual) the forecast is then calculated using these 2 columns. The Actual figure added every day is difference from any past data, but any data already added never changes. I need to work out how to get the same result for past forecasts to verify future forecasts can be calculated in the same way that they used to.

Comment: Now I think I understand. You use the data in column "Actual" to calculate new data in column "Forecast". One simple way, possibly not helpful, is to create some histograms, to see the "distribution" of values for the forecast. If you can notice some values with higher count, then analyze the data behind, see if you can find a "correlation".